# Could not find method pdf(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute

Tags: java, android, android-layout, intellij-idea-2020

Below is the button code

```
 <Button
                   android:id="@+id/button_encode"
                    android:text="@string/encode"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/spn"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                    android:fontFamily="TimesRoman"
                    android:background="#AD0009"
                    android:textColor="#F1F7FF"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:onClick="pdf"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
```

Below is the on Click method that allows me to convert the info stored in a spinner into a pdf document

```
   public void pdf(View view) {
            final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_url);
            final Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spn);
            String code = sp.getItemAtPosition(sp.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
            //"Encode" button
            final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_encode);
            final Button btnpdfqr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pdfqr);
            final Button ad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
            //Set action to button
            final int STORAGE_CODE = 1;
            Intent qrDroid = new Intent(Services.ENCODE); //Set action "la.droid.qr.encode"
    
            //Set text to encode
            qrDroid.putExtra(Services.CODE, code);
            Document mDoc = new Document();
    
            //The pdf
            String mFileName = sp.getItemAtPosition(sp.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
    
            //pdf file path
            String mFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/NHS_PDF/" + "Amox" + ".pdf";
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            try {
                //create instance of PdfWriter class
                PdfWriter.getInstance(mDoc, new FileOutputStream(mFilePath));
                //open the document for writing
                mDoc.open();
                //get text from EditText i.e. mTextEt
    
    
                //add author of the document (optional)
                mDoc.addAuthor("Bingham");
    
                //add paragraph to the document
                mDoc.add(new Paragraph(mFileName));
    
                //close the document
                mDoc.close();
                //show message that file is saved, it will show file name and file path too
                Toast.makeText(NHSEncode.this, mFileName + ".pdf\nis saved to\n" + mFilePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //if any thing goes wrong causing exception, get and show exception message
                Toast.makeText(NHSEncode.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            //Check whether an URL or an imge is required
            if (spinner.getSelectedItemId() == 0) { //First item selected ("Get Bitmap")
                //Notify we want complete results (default is FALSE)
                image = true;
                qrDroid.putExtra(Services.IMAGE, true);
                //Optionally, set requested image size. 0 means "Fit Screen"
                qrDroid.putExtra(Services.SIZE, 0);
            } else {
                image = false;
            }
    
            //Send intent and wait result
            try {
                startActivityForResult(qrDroid, ACTIVITY_RESULT_QR_DRDROID);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activity) {
                Services.qrDroidRequired(NHSEncode.this);
            }
        }
```

Below is the Error message that I receive when clicking the button that is meant to convert the spinner info into a pdf document

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method pdf(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button_encode'
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:447)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:405)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7862)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:15004)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7831)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:879)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29359)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
2021-03-08 10:53:56.639 8008-8243/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '53aceec com.example.infoapp/com.example.infoapp.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2021-03-08 10:53:56.640 10397-10397/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2021-03-08 10:53:56.642 10397-10397/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2021-03-08 10:53:56.647 8008-10671/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{53aceec u0 com.example.infoapp/com.example.infoapp.MainActivity EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=0 caller=com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:1248 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:1229 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5182 com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$01bPtngJg5AqEoOWfW3rWfV7MH4.accept:2 java.util.ArrayList.forEach:1262 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.onAnimationFinished:3931 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.commitVisibility:913 
2021-03-08 10:53:56.666 10397-10397/? E/android.dqagen: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2021-03-08 10:53:56.687 27043-27247/? E/PBSessionCacheImpl: sessionId[118937986688457744] not persisted.
2021-03-08 10:53:56.699 8650-8650/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2021-03-08 10:53:56.742 8650-8650/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2021-03-08 10:53:57.147 8008-8287/? E/MobileWipsFrameworkService: unbinded can not send 12
2021-03-08 10:53:57.484 8774-8774/? E/ApduServiceInfo: Not adding <aid-group> with empty or invalid AIDs
2021-03-08 10:53:57.485 8774-8774/? E/ApduServiceInfo: ###---
2021-03-08 10:53:57.487 8440-8440/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
2021-03-08 10:53:57.490 8440-8440/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
2021-03-08 10:53:57.506 8774-8774/? E/ApduServiceInfo: Not adding <aid-group> with empty or invalid AIDs
2021-03-08 10:53:57.506 8774-8774/? E/ApduServiceInfo: ###---
2021-03-08 10:53:58.974 26565-10452/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2021-03-08 10:53:59.112 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:53:59.411 8008-8287/? E/MobileWipsFrameworkService: unbinded can not send 13
2021-03-08 10:54:00.506 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:54:03.236 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:54:05.514 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:54:08.063 688-688/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1615200848.055:38750): avc:  denied  { kill } for  pid=0 comm="swapper/0" capability=5  scontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=capability permissive=0 SEPF_SM-A715F_10_0022 audit_filtered
2021-03-08 10:54:10.521 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:54:12.525 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:54:14.022 8650-8650/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2021-03-08 10:54:14.044 8650-8650/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2021-03-08 10:54:14.448 7824-7845/? E/Netd: getNetworkForDns: getNetId from enterpriseCtrl is netid 0
2021-03-08 10:54:14.579 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:54:14.871 26565-2367/? E/SQLiteCastStore: Skip saving CastDeviceInfo: "Nearby device" (__cast_nearby___V_4a86f223-3d53-42dd-8348-806b56453fce)
2021-03-08 10:54:15.524 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:54:15.622 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:54:16.662 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:54:17.709 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:54:20.442 8008-8080/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 6045 [2021-03-08 10:54:20.441] FD count : 802, wdog_way : softdog
2021-03-08 10:54:20.531 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:54:20.792 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:54:22.846 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:54:25.537 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:54:30.538 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:54:30.915 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:54:32.710 7824-7845/? E/Netd: getNetworkForDns: getNetId from enterpriseCtrl is netid 0
2021-03-08 10:54:33.080 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:54:33.966 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:54:35.544 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:54:36.203 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:54:40.550 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:54:41.351 21318-21318/? E/Finsky: [2] aqgb.run(3): Error while cleaning up task
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.TimeoutFuture$TimeoutFutureException: Timed out: cmg@bb662ab[status=PENDING, info=[tag=[class apjw]]]
        at bbzu.s(PG:3)
        at bbzu.get(PG:2)
        at bccv.a(PG:1)
        at bcbq.r(Unknown Source:9)
        at aqgb.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
     Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.TimeoutFuture$TimeoutFutureException: Timed out: cmg@bb662ab[status=PENDING, info=[tag=[class apjw]]]
2021-03-08 10:54:42.354 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:54:43.122 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:54:45.556 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:54:48.545 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:54:49.593 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:54:50.456 8008-8080/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 6046 [2021-03-08 10:54:50.455] FD count : 802, wdog_way : softdog
2021-03-08 10:54:50.563 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:54:53.726 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:54:54.788 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:54:55.569 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:55:00.041 8650-8650/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2021-03-08 10:55:00.051 8650-8650/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2021-03-08 10:55:00.576 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:55:05.583 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:55:08.073 688-688/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1615200908.055:38751): avc:  denied  { kill } for  pid=0 comm="swapper/0" capability=5  scontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=capability permissive=0 SEPF_SM-A715F_10_0022 audit_filtered
2021-03-08 10:55:09.173 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:55:10.210 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:55:10.588 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:55:12.273 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:55:15.596 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:55:18.450 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:55:19.487 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:55:20.462 8008-8080/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 6047 [2021-03-08 10:55:20.462] FD count : 802, wdog_way : softdog
2021-03-08 10:55:20.523 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:55:20.602 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:55:21.569 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:55:22.606 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:55:23.642 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:55:25.605 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:55:25.734 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:55:27.811 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:55:28.887 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:55:29.891 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:55:30.612 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:55:35.618 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:55:37.096 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:55:38.069 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:55:40.624 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:55:45.625 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:55:49.212 26565-18858/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2021-03-08 10:55:50.476 8008-8080/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 6048 [2021-03-08 10:55:50.476] FD count : 802, wdog_way : softdog
2021-03-08 10:55:50.631 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:55:52.473 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:55:53.366 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:55:54.543 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:55:55.634 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:55:57.633 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:55:58.682 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:55:59.490 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:56:00.053 8650-8650/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2021-03-08 10:56:00.070 8650-8650/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2021-03-08 10:56:00.081 8008-8088/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for bluetooth
2021-03-08 10:56:00.118 8008-8088/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-03-08 10:56:00.118 8008-8088/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-03-08 10:56:00.639 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:56:01.791 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:56:02.538 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:56:05.645 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:56:08.078 688-688/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1615200968.055:38752): avc:  denied  { kill } for  pid=0 comm="swapper/0" capability=5  scontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=capability permissive=0 SEPF_SM-A715F_10_0022 audit_filtered
2021-03-08 10:56:10.648 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:56:15.653 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:56:17.806 8440-8440/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
2021-03-08 10:56:17.823 8774-8774/? E/ApduServiceInfo: Not adding <aid-group> with empty or invalid AIDs
2021-03-08 10:56:17.824 8774-8774/? E/ApduServiceInfo: ###---
2021-03-08 10:56:20.490 8008-8080/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 6049 [2021-03-08 10:56:20.490] FD count : 802, wdog_way : softdog
2021-03-08 10:56:20.659 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:56:23.907 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:56:25.411 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:56:25.666 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:56:28.504 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:56:29.576 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:56:30.669 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:56:35.675 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:56:36.128 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:56:37.779 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:56:38.827 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:56:39.188 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:56:40.681 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:56:41.947 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:56:42.246 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:56:44.008 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:56:45.056 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:56:45.687 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:56:50.512 8008-8080/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 6050 [2021-03-08 10:56:50.511] FD count : 802, wdog_way : softdog
2021-03-08 10:56:50.693 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:56:55.697 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:57:00.038 8650-8650/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2021-03-08 10:57:00.055 8650-8650/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2021-03-08 10:57:00.703 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:57:03.571 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:57:05.705 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:57:07.825 14304-10502/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2021-03-08 10:57:08.083 688-688/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1615201028.065:38753): avc:  denied  { kill } for  pid=0 comm="swapper/0" capability=5  scontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=capability permissive=0 SEPF_SM-A715F_10_0022 audit_filtered
2021-03-08 10:57:10.708 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:57:11.562 16782-23755/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2021-03-08 10:57:13.843 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:57:14.881 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:57:15.715 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:57:20.528 8008-8080/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 6051 [2021-03-08 10:57:20.528] FD count : 802, wdog_way : softdog
2021-03-08 10:57:20.723 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:57:21.137 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:57:25.728 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:57:30.737 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:57:34.738 16782-10505/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2021-03-08 10:57:35.464 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:57:35.743 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:57:36.529 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:57:40.745 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:57:45.751 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:57:46.050 7824-7845/? E/Netd: getNetworkForDns: getNetId from enterpriseCtrl is netid 0
2021-03-08 10:57:50.543 8008-8080/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 6052 [2021-03-08 10:57:50.543] FD count : 802, wdog_way : softdog
2021-03-08 10:57:50.756 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:57:53.623 20634-20834/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2021-03-08 10:57:55.763 3319-3348/? E/perfsdkserver: [Interface] BpPerfSDKService::connectionRequest() 
2021-03-08 10:57:57.032 12253-12253/? E/HONEYBOARD: c activeNetwork is null 
2021-03-08 10:57:58.113 14304-9870/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
```

How do I resolve this error that allows me to embed text that is stored in the spinner into a pdf document that can be stored onto a mobile device

Comment: Add source code how you are calling `pdf` class... I think it needed according to error. `Could not find method pdf(View) in a parent`

Comment: The android:onClick="pdf" line within the button code is meant to call the method public void pdf(View view)

Comment: Oh! Sorry I didn't look at that..

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `pdf class`.

```
public void pdf(View view)
```

You have an argument on pdf class(`View`). While you are calling the class from `android:onClick="pdf"`. You are unable to send any argument.That's why the error is occurring.

> Error : Could not find method pdf(**View**) in a parent

You can try by removing `View` argument.

```
public void pdf()
```

Try the following source code instead of `android:onClick="pdf"`

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            pdf();
        }

}
```

Comment: Your edited answer doesn't work, I am still getting the same error as mentioned above